# Parsing Python's If Statement with Scala

Tags: python, scala, parsing, if-statement

How would you parse an If Statement in Python with Scala?

Right now I have something like this:

```
import fastparse.all._

val ifStatement : P[Stmt] = P (
      ("if " ~ expr ~ ":" ~ ("\n".rep.? ~ "\t".rep.?) ~ stmt ~ ("\n".rep.? ~ "\t".rep.?) ~ "else:" ~ stmt).map {
        case (e, st1, st2) => If (e, st1, st2)
      }
    )
```

stmt is basically a val with statements:

```
val stmt: Parser[StatementStuff] = P ("\n".rep.? ~ "\t".rep.? ~
          ( returnStatement | statement | assignStatement |
            forLoop |  blockBody | print | printString |
            ifStatement )
          )
```

I want to be able to parse Python's Fizzbuzz:

```
def main():
    count = 0
    for count in range(1, 101):
        if count % 5 == 0 and count % 3 == 0:
            print "FizzBuzz"
        elif count % 3 == 0:
            print "Fizz"
        elif count % 5 == 0:
            print "Buzz"
        else:
            print count
    count = count + 1
```

Right now I can handle if statements like this for example:

```
if x==0:
   return poo
```

But I would like to handle something like:
    if count % 5 == 0 and count % 3 == 0:

any help would be wonderful, thank you in advance!

Parser library: http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/

Comment: Might be worth mentioning which libraries you're using.

Comment: Could you provide something that's [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I am using import fastparse.all._

Answer (score 2):

FastParse was updated with a [pythonParser](https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse/tree/master/pythonparse/shared/src/main/scala/pythonparse), which might be helpful in parsing python.